# Dojo dgrid - change cell value based on another cells value

Tags: ajax, dojo, dgrid

I have a `dgrid`. It is connected to a `store` and to a `database`.
I have a `column` in the `dgrid`, called `type`.
There is another `column`, called `subtype`. It takes it's `parentid` values from `type`.

I would like to add a `FilteringSelect` to the `subtype` `column`. When this `FilteringSelect` changes, I would like to pass the `parentid` value to the `type` `column` and display it, so change the value of the `type` `column` to the value based on the selection in the `subtype` `column`.

How can I achieve this?

I am having trouble with cross referencing the `columns`...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the data you will need will be in the event object for the `"dgrid-datachange` handler.

```
yourdGrid.on("dgrid-datachange",function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

The `event` object has within it the store data pertaining to that row in `event.cell.row.data`

That should allow you to access `parentid`